# Marketing Cloud not working properly

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, contactbuilder

I am experiencing some errors with the Marketing Cloud particularly with Contact Builder and the display of population, attribute groups, and channel order as well as the journey builder when setting up a new entry event (in that case I cannot continue and set filters due to a never ending pre loader).

An error message appearing:

[image]

> An error occurred during loading this procedure

It is asking to try again later or contact global support if the error endures.

Since there is no further error message, I cannot be more precise than this. However this error occurred twice the last couple days.

Comment: I suggest opening the developer tools of your browser and checking the network tab for any failing request, as the response-payload may give additional error details.

Comment: I would also contact Global Support - these issues are exactly what they are there to help with.